# XAS Parser Android

Tags: java, android, sax, saxparser

Not able to find the mistake in below code, it is parsing the xml but the characters function is not getting the bName and bDescription updated, it always shows zero, so I'm not able to set those values in my object.

### Java Class

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.tech.reader.utils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import com.tech.reader.R;
import com.tech.reader.models.Book;
import com.tech.reader.models.Note;

import android.content.Context;

/**
 * @author hafsalrahman
 * 
 */
public class NoteParser extends DefaultHandler {

    ArrayList<Note> bookL;

    String bookXmlFileName;

    Note bookTmp;
    Boolean bName = false, bDescription = false;
    Context c;

    // SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd");

    public NoteParser(Context c, int i) {

        this.bookXmlFileName = fetchFilename(i);
        this.c = c;
        bookL = new ArrayList<Note>();

        parseDocument();

    }

    private String fetchFilename(int i) {
        String s = null;
        if (i == 0) {
            s = "note_" + i + ".xml";
        }
        return s;
    }

    private void parseDocument() {

        // parse

        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();

        try {

            SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
            InputStream is = null;
            // System.out.print(bookXmlFileName);
            try {
                is = c.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.note1_0);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage() + "no message__");
            }

            if (is != null)
                parser.parse(new InputSource(is), this);

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {

            System.out.println("ParserConfig error");

        } catch (SAXException e) {

            System.out.println("SAXException : xml not well formed");

        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println("IO error");

        }

    }

    public ArrayList<Note> outputDatas() {

        for (Note tmpB : bookL) {

            System.out.println(tmpB.toString());

        }
        return bookL;
    }

    public Object[] outputNames() {

        ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (Note tmpB : bookL) {

            temp.add(tmpB.getName().toString());

        }
        return temp.toArray();
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String elementName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

        if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase("Note")) {
            // create a new Employee and put it in Map
            String id = attributes.getValue("id");
            // initialize Employee object and set id attribute
            bookTmp = new Note();
            // bookTmp.setId(id);
            // initialize list
            if (bookL == null)
                bookL = new ArrayList<Note>();
        } else if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
            // set boolean values for fields, will be used in setting Employee
            // variables
            bName = true;
        } else if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase("descr")) {
            bDescription = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String s, String s1, String element)
            throws SAXException {

        // if end of book element add to list

        if (element.equals("note")) {

            bookL.add(bookTmp);
            // System.out.println("book added" + bookTmp.getId());

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ac, int i, int j) throws SAXException {

        System.out.println("chars=" + new String(ac, i, j));

        if (bName) {
            // age element, set Employee age
            bookTmp.setName(new String(ac, i, j));
            bName = false;
        } else if (bDescription) {
            bookTmp.setDescription(new String(ac, i, j));
            bDescription = false;
        }

    }

}
```

### XML to read

> ```
> <note id="1" >
>     <title> Note1
>     </title>
>
>     <descr> look at creating applications 
>   with XML.
>     </descr>
> </note>
> <note id="2" >
>     <title> Note2
>     </title>
>
>     <descr> look at creating applications 
>   with XML.
>     </descr>
> </note>
> <note id="3" >
>     <title> Note3
>     </title>
>
>     <descr> look at creating applications 
>   with XML. 
>     </descr>
> </note>
> <note id="4" >
>     <title> Note4
>     </title>
>
>     <descr> look at creating applications 
>   with XML.
>     </descr>
> </note>
> <note id="5" >
>     <title> Note5
>     </title>
>
>     <descr> look at creating applications 
>   with XML.
>     </descr>
> </note>
> <note id="6" >
>     <title> Note6
>     </title>
>
>     <descr> look at creating applications 
>   with XML.
>     </descr>
> </note>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your characters function there is no guarantee that the data in the char[] array is ready or finished. What you should do is make a StringBuilder and accumulate it in characters(). Then when done, process the result in endElement()